# Does Debug.LogAssert gets deleted in Unity once I build the game?

Tags: unity, debugging

Does `Debug.LogAssert(expression)` gets deleted in Unity once I build the game?

I was not able to find it [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Assert.html). I feel like it should get deleted, but still I can not assure myself in it (no reliable source was found by me).

So, I would be grateful for the source provided which would assure me in it or point me out, that it is not the case.

Comment: Just try it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `Debug.Assert` gets removed from non-development builds by default. It's possible to change this setting - see the Unity documentation on [BuildOptions.ForceEnableAssertions](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildOptions.ForceEnableAssertions.html):

> BuildOptions.ForceEnableAssertions
>
> Include assertions in the build. By default, the assertions are only included in development builds.

Comment: As a side note, there are also interesting posts here with varied opinions on whether asserts should be included with a release build: [When should assertions stay in production code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17732/5170571) and [Should there be assertions in release builds](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/364145/302601)